# How to prevent api call when back button is clicked in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

Will localStorage help me to go back the previous route without calling the api. Can anyone suggest me with an example?

In content.js

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("state", JSON.stringify(this.state))
  }
```

In alert.js

```
goToAlert = () => {
  localStorage.getItem("state");
  this.props.history.push("/content");
}
    <div
       onClick={this.goToAlert}
    >
     <img
      src={BackArrowButton}
      alt="back-arrow"
    />
    </div>
```

Comment: Show me the code, please.

Comment: Do you own the code that calls the API? Don't run that code if a flag is set.